# Getting IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, exception, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to implement Turing machine on C#. I convert word to chart array and work with array.

```
      public TuringMachine(String word) {
            word = " " + word + " ";
            tapeArray = word.ToCharArray();  
        }
```

I have to detect line/string/word that ends in number 1.
So if I input `1010100101`, I get this

```
>1 
>Word ends in 1
```

But if I input `10101010`, I get `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Here full code:

```
public class TuringMachine {
        char[] tapeArray;
        int N;
        char a0 = ' ';
        int i = 1;

       public TuringMachine(String word) {
            word = " " + word + " ";
            tapeArray = word.ToCharArray();
            N = tapeArray.Length;
            State1();
        }

        public void State1() {
            if (tapeArray[i] == '1') {
                tapeArray[i] = '1';
                i = i + 1;
                State1();
            }
            if(tapeArray[i] == '0') {
                tapeArray[i] = '0';
                i = i + 1;
                State1();
            }
            if (tapeArray[i] == a0) {
                tapeArray[i] = a0;
                i = i - 1;
                State2();
            }
        }

        public void State2() {
            if (tapeArray[i] == '1') {
                tapeArray[i] = a0;
                i = i - 1;
                State3();
            }
            if (tapeArray[i] == '0') {
                tapeArray[i] = a0;
                i = i - 1;
                State4();
            }
        }

        public void State3() {
            if (tapeArray[i] == '1') {
                tapeArray[i] = a0;
                i = i - 1;
                State3();
            }
            if (tapeArray[i] == '0') {
                tapeArray[i] = a0;
                i = i - 1;
                State3();
            }
            if (tapeArray[i] == a0) {
                tapeArray[i] = '1';
            }
        }

        public void State4() {
            if (tapeArray[i] == '1') {
                tapeArray[i] = a0;
                i = i - 1;
                State4();
            }
            if (tapeArray[i] == '0') {
                tapeArray[i] = a0;
                i = i - 1;
                State4();
            }
            if (tapeArray[i] == a0) {
                tapeArray[i] = '0';
                i = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain why I get `IndexOutOfRangeException` ?

Sorry for bad English

Comment: you need to make sure `i < tapeArray.Length && i >= 0`

Comment: @NedStoyanov but why my code continue do the folowing `i = i - 1`? And only if I input `0` at the end of word.

Comment: change your `if` statements to `if/else if` statements.Once you get to index `0` in `State4` and the number is a `1`, you still execute the `0` part after that and try to access `tapeArray[-1]`